# CSS Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to keep my page from having to horizontally scroll.

When I add my navbar and header div to my page, everything works fine. However, when I add my content div it forces my page to scroll left and right. It's no wider than my header so why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;

    background: url(/style/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    <!-- FOR IE -->
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(68,105,244,.45);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(68,105,244,.45);
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(68,105,244,.45);


}

.divstyle {
    background-color: rgba(247,247,247,.9);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#navbar {
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 1600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

}

#header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#content {
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<div id="navbar" class="divstyle">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>      
</div>

<div id="header" class="divstyle">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>      
</div>

<div id="content" class="divstyle">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>      
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mRHT/

Comment: Could you link to your page?  I tried reconstructing via code pen and without data there's no issue

Comment: reproduce the problem in a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) for us

Comment: The content div is 1000px wide...how big is the screen you're testing on? If it's not that wide (and it probably should be in the year 2014) you're going to get a scrollbar.

Comment: I retract, I see the issue now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tKjDB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of `min-width: 1600px;` present in

```
#navbar {
height: 50px;
/* min-width: 1600px; */
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

This will remove the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: yup, i must have overlooked that. I don't even remember adding that in there haha. Thanks for the help!